# PHP with active xdebug handles 0 values as null

Tags: xdebug, php-8.1

#### Description

`xdebug` seems to handle `0` as well as `"0"` values as `null` values if it is enabled **and** PhpStorm actively listens to incoming connections.

If `xdebug` is enabled but PhpStorm **doesn't listen** to connections ("the debugger is disabled" - so to speak), the website works perfectly fine.

If `xdebug` is disabled and PhpStorm **doesn't listen** to connections, the website works perfectly fine.

#### Example

This results in different errors in a Magento 2 project. And it seems this primarily occurs in PHPs magic functions like `__call` (`\Magento\Framework\DataObject::__call`). But that's just a guess and really hard to say as I'm always getting the right values if every step is debugged (`0` stays `0`).

I'm working on a Ubuntu machine with a PHP docker container.

`php -v` outputs the following information:

```
PHP 8.1.12 (cli) (built: Oct 28 2022 17:39:37) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.12, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.1.12, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.1.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2022, by Derick Rethans
```

`xdebug` is configured as follows:

```ini
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.start_with_request = default
xdebug.client_host = "${HOST_IP}"
xdebug.client_port = 9000
xdebug.discover_client_host = false
xdebug.idekey = "PHPSTORM"

; xdebug error handling
xdebug.force_display_errors = 0
xdebug.halt_level = 0
xdebug.show_error_trace = 0
xdebug.show_exception_trace = 0

xdebug.scream = 0
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 512
```

Are there any known bugs or fixes for this issue?

Comment: Xdebug does not change values itself. You're going to have to make a (small) reproducible example, and add a xdebug log. See what you'd need (just like for any bug report really), at https://xdebug.org/reporting-bugs

Comment: yeah, I've tried to reproduce it. I've created a custom `DataObject` class with a magic function but that works perfectly fine. The thing is I don't exactly know where PHP converts from `0` to `null` because if I take every debugging step, the issue does not occur. If xdebug is off, it doesn't occur. I just don't know exactly, how to create a reproducible example that behaves the same.